# Links on the page, when being printed, have the URL next to them

Tags: css

I'm attempting to create a print.css stylesheet for my site and I'm running into an interesting problem.

When I print any page on my site, all the links on the page are printing the URL directly next to it and it's causing all kinds of styling issues. At first I thought it might be my browser or printer, but other sites don't have this issue. Is there some setting in the admin section to remove these? I'm using the Boilerplate theme, which may be causing this issue.

Comment: Close-voted as *off topic*. This is a **CSS** (or a **browser**) question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably some code like this in your stylesheet:

```
@media print
{
    a::after
    {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }
}
```

Remove it and the URLs are not printed anymore.

Comment: Most definately a possible cause, good thinking.. +1 ..